# I get file not found exception trying to open a linked file in my assets folder (android)

Tags: android

I have a file in my assests folder, that I imported using the 'link' option (as opposed to copy). I use the following code to open it, but I get a file not found exception.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.bar_page_lo);
appContext = getApplicationContext();
InputStream ins;
ins = appContext.getResources().getAssets().open("bar-data.json");
```

I need it to be linked because the file is in a dropbox folder so that my colleague can edit it. is there something special I need to do to use a linked file?

Comment: Are you sure bar-data.json is in assets ? And not in subfolder ?

Comment: ok turns out the problem was that when I dragged the file into the assets folder, I chose the 'link to file' instead of 'copy'. But shouldn't the link feature work?

Comment: No, when android compiles, it gets everything that is inside assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 appContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.bar-data);
```

File must be placed in raw folder.

Comment: `R.raw.bar-data` is not a valid identifier.